# Can't compile Python using Nuitka

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, nuitka

I'm trying to compile Python file which uses urllib.request, BeautifulSoup, and
webbrowser.

```
$ nuitka python.py
Nuitka:WARNING:python.py:16: Cannot find 'urllib.request' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:python.py:17: Cannot find 'bs4' as relative or absolute import.

$ ./python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 16, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request
```

Comment: I don't know what nuitka is, but `no module named request` looks an awful lot like a python2 v. python3 mismatch.

Comment: Include the import statements for bs4 and request in your question, and also your file names.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `--recurse-to=urllib` to command line during Nuitka execution.
See Nuitka help for details.

Answer (score 0):

You have both python2 and python3 installed in your system
check python version usin

```
$python --version
```

urllib.request will only be missing if nuitka is using python2 to compile your python3 code.
there is no urllib.request in python2.7

same with bs4 ..

there is python2 lurking in your system somewhere and nuitka is using that to compile your python3 code

to ensure python3 is used

```
$/path to python3/python -m nuitka program.py
```

or  where python 3.7 is aliased as python3

```
$python3 -m nuitka program.py
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Nuitka to compile Python programs to standalone executables,then
redistribute them without the Python runtime

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33503722)

Answer (score -2):

You can use different compiler like pycharm or the VScode to compile your python code.

Comment: Neither pycharm or vscode are compilers